# Set listview item button to load specific url without declaring final listview data?

Tags: java, android

So I was having an issue before with the URL's not loading correctly, and I've fixed that, but now I can't figure out how to set OnClick to load a specific URL since I need to declare it final, but I can't otherwise it won't work properly.

(I'm somewhat new to Java/Android)

Here's DietyAdapter.java,

```
public class deityListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<deities> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
deities data[] = null;
deities deity;

public deityListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, deities data[]) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View ListItem = convertView;
    Holder holder;

    if (ListItem == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        ListItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.description = (TextView)ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityDesc);
        holder.banner = (ImageView)ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityBanner);
        holder.website = (Button)ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityWebsite);
        ListItem.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (Holder) ListItem.getTag();
    }
    deities deity = data[position];

    View.OnClickListener holderListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WebView webView = (WebView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.loadUrl(deity.url); // i want this to work without declaring diety to be final
        }
    }



    holder.banner.setImageResource(deity.banner);
    holder.description.setText(deity.description);
    holder.banner.setBackgroundColor(deity.color);
    holder.description.setText(deity.url);
    return ListItem;

}
static class Holder {

    TextView description;
    ImageView banner;
    Button website;



  }

}
```

Dieties.java

```
public class deities {

public int banner;
public String description;
public String url;
public int color;
public int id;
public deities(){
    super();
}

public deities(int banner, String description, String url, int id, int color){
    super();
    this.banner = banner;
    this.description = description;
    this.url = url;
    this.color = color;
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    deities deity_data[] = new deities[]
            {
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 1", "http://google.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#ff3399")),
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 2", "http://facebook.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#9933ff")),
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 3", "http://youtube.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#0099ff")),
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 4", "http://pinterest.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#009900")),
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 5", "http://twitter.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#cc0000")),
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 6", "http://facepunch.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#0000cc")),
                    new deities(R.drawable.transparent, "Test 7", "http://linustechtips.com", 1, Color.parseColor("#333300"))

            };
    deityListAdapter adapter = new deityListAdapter(this,
            R.layout.deity_list_item, deity_data);

    ListView deityList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.deityList);
    deityList.setAdapter(adapter);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            ProgressBar webViewProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.webViewProgress);
            webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webViewProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);






}


@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.webViewProgress);
    if (webView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Back up a second. What happens when you declare deity as final?

Comment: I'm such a fool, sorry, it works absolutely fine. I figured if it was final it'd be stuck under one position, and it was acting funny already when I tried it (but due to other problems). Thanks for all your help regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In getView method of adapter, use setTag on Button view like this:

```
     holder.website.setTag(data[position].url);
```

And implement View.OnClickListener in your adapter like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.deityWebsite) {

        String url = (String) v.getTag();
        //implement your code here with url
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Changing it to final actually worked fine but I'm going to mark this as the correct answer since it addresses the question, and is just helpful in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you create a listener but never use it. Somewhere you need to call `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: I did in the code, I must have changed something and forgotten to put it back in, whoops.